# Why I can't get tr elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I work

HTML(The HTML part is generated via a JSON, this is just the template.) :

```
<table id="table-blog" class="order-table table table-hover">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Tags</th>
         <th>Url</th>
         <th>Active</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Title</td>
          <td>Description</td>
          <td>Tags</td>
          <td>Url</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Tags</td>
        <td>Url</td>
       <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Tags</td>
        <td>Url</td>
       <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here the JS :

```
function syncBlog(blogs)
  {
    blogs = Object.values(blogs);
   
    var tbody =  $("#table-blog > tbody");
      console.log($(tbody).children());
    $(tbody).children().each(function(){
      $(this).children('td:last-child').children("input").prop("checked", false);
    });
    
    if(blogs.length > 0)
    {
      blogs.forEach(blog => 
      {
        $(tbody).children().each(function(){
          console.log($(this));
          if($(this).children('td:first').text() == blog.title)
          {
            console.log(blogs);
            $(this).children('td:last-child').children("input").prop("checked", true);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

I don't why `.children()` returns nothing, however the table is filled before (by ajax call).

But if I try with native JS :

```
var tbody =  document.querySelector("#table-blog > tbody");
console.log(tbody.children);
```

I will be able to see the `HTMLCollection` with all `<tr>`, but I can't use them and `.length` return me 0

Comment: Note: `:last-child` will select multiple last children (one per parent (tr in this case)), you don't need to loop the `tr` for this.  If you used `td:last` then yes, it would only give you one.   `$("#table-blog > tbody > tr > td:last-child > input").prop("checked", false)`

Comment: You should be using `tbody.children()` and not `$(tbody).children()` since your already setting `var tbody = $("#table-blog > tbody")`

Comment: This question would benefit from a complete snippet, including your HTML and a sample for `blogs`.  With some extrapolation and a contrived value for blogs, your [code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/1x05fpq2/).   Looping through `tbody.children()` then `$(this).children('td:first').text()` works fine.  So perhaps the issue is only with `==blog.title` or `blogs = Object.values(blogs)`.   `.children(filter)` works fine.

Comment: @slashroot with $ or whitout still the same result...

Comment: @freedomn-m the problem is, I never go on this forEach because $(tbody).children() return nothing. But in the debugger I see tr tags. So the question was, why $(tbody).children() return nothing, while everything is loaded well before the call of the function, so no problem of undefined because, I see well the elements in the debuger

Comment: Can you add to your code an example of your html sttructure?

Comment: Have a read of [mcve].  Include *only* the *relevant* parts to your question.  If your issue is about the first line then don't include all the others as it just redirects our attention.  In this case, you've not provided any evidence of why `$(tbody).children()` would return 0 and there's plenty of evidence that it doesn't - so there **must** be something not included in what you've provided.  So you need to provide enough to demonstrate the problem.  Simply saying *$(tbody).children() doesn't work* is not enough as it clearly does, on its own.

Comment: Maybe your `id=table-blog` doesn't exist?  Maybe it's not a `table`?  Maybe it doesn't have a `tbody` (though the browser would add one)?  There's 1000s of reasons, none of which are included in your question.  Please add them.

Comment: @SaeedShamloo I add ;)

Comment: The "children" part of the code works fine with the stated structure - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qabko6hf/ (I even pre-checked one of the checkboxes just to prove it will uncheck it again). You can also see in the console that it logs all the elements it found.

Comment: If you console.log HTMLCollection and you console log length which gives you zero, it means the collection is filled later. console.log doesn't give you a snapshot of the collection, only a reference to the object. If the collection is filled with elements later, then you can see elements in the console. Which means that you call this function before the DOM is built.

Comment: @wawka i see what you mean but, the strange things is, with when I do console.log(tbody)  I see the list of tr and I can access to DOM

Comment: But again, that's because the console gets a _reference_ to the object...so if it _later_ gets filled, the console will retrospectively populate the log entry with the data. For me that's unhelpful, but that's how it is. Use the JS debugger to break on that line and see what's there at that moment. Or you can try to log JSON.stringify(tbody) to get a static, in-the-moment log of the data. The only explanation for what you're seeing really is that the HTML table (or at least its content) isn't added to the DOM until after your function runs. As I've shown, the code will work if the HTML exists.

Comment: @ADyson Ok my bad, so the best way is, I have to wait until the DOM is complete

Comment: Yes. That's true in any code of any sort - you can't run code on data which doesn't exist yet. Wait for the data to be populated, then run whatever you need. In your case, it sounds like that means hooking into an AJAX call's "done" event.

Comment: @ADyson ok great I'll try it,  If I succeed, I upload the solution.

Comment: So the bit I mentioned earlier that's not included in the question:  You're running your code *before* the HTML exists...

Comment: The debugging test is to output the `.length` in a console.log as part of the code - ie something that forces `$(this)` or `.children()` to resolve at that time, not later on in the console / element browser.

Answer (score -2):

Well,
Thank you all for your answers.
I was able to find the solution that now seems clear.
The DOM was not fully loaded before the execution of the function.
To solve the problem I made my AJAX call in synchronous:
Exemple:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'Your url',
        methode:'POST',//In my case
        data:'Your data',
        success:function(),
        error:function(),
        async:false, 
       });
```

Comment: That's a _terrible_ solution. Synchronous AJAX is deprecated in modern browsers, so you can't expect it to work forever. In Chrome at least, you'll get a Console warning as a reward for this foolishness. Why is it deprecated? Because it causes a horrible user experience, where the whole browser UI locks up during AJAX requests (because JS is single-threaded) and users can't see what's going on. If there is lots of AJAX, or it's long-running, the page becomes unusuable and the user gets really frustrated, and maybe kills the browser because they think it's crashed.

Comment: The correct solution, as I hinted at above, is to handle the "done" (or "success" if you prefer) callback of the AJAX request, and run your function from there, so you can be sure that the AJAX has completed.

Comment: Also `methode` is a typo

Comment: @ADyson Ok I see thanks